# JQuery find between two text values

Tags: jquery, text

I am running this code into my jquery script, with this method i can detect only values that are higher or lower but not between them.

For example: the first statement says lower than 1.

How to change it and make between 0-1.

Second statement between 1-29...

Third statement 29-49 and so on...

The code works fine, just need that between, because the statement with higher value overwrite all the others... Any thoughts ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.table td').each(function(){
            if($(this).text() <1) {
                $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
            }
            else if($(this).text() <29) {
                $(this).css('background-color','#9A271C');
            }
            else if($(this).text() <49) {
                $(this).css('background-color','#BA650E');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `&&` and while you use `.text()` I think you will need `parseInt();` as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.table td').each(function(){
            var ThisNumber = parseInt($(this).text());
            if( ThisNumber  < 1) {                           // less than 1
                $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
            }
            else if( ThisNumber  >= 1 && ThisNumber <29) {   //between 1 - 29
                $(this).css('background-color','#9A271C');
            }
            else if( ThisNumber >= 29 && ThisNumber <49) {   // between 29-49
                $(this).css('background-color','#BA650E');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be misinterpreting what is going on. Since you have an "else if" the second condition will only best tested if the first one fails - so in your example the test for < 29 will only happen if the value is >= 1. Hence I think you code is correct but there might be something more subtle in how it is being run. Without the rest of your code it is hard to tell where things are going wrong.

In my original answer I missed the subtlety of the equals case - hence, working on Mohamed's answer but keeping it simple the code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table td').each(function(){
        var ThisNumber = parseInt($(this).text());
        if( ThisNumber  <= 1) {                           // less than 1
            $(this).css('background-color','#fff');
        }
        else if(ThisNumber <=29) {   //between 1 - 29
            $(this).css('background-color','#9A271C');
        }
        else if(ThisNumber <=49) {   // between 29-49
            $(this).css('background-color','#BA650E');
        }
    });
});
```

i.e just change the '<' to '<='

Answer (score 2):

How to change it and make between 0-1 
wouldn't that be <= 1

Second statement between 1-29
should be  <=29 since 1 and below would trigger first and shut down the if.

Third statement 29-49 and so on... 
Would be <=49 since the previous if triggers would fire if it was less than 29...  I'm no expert but I know a little.

Answer (score 1):

By saying "between 0-1" and "between 1-29" you're forgetting about 1 itself! If you want to include a number (meaning from 0 up to *and including* 1), put `<=` instead of `<`, such as

```
if($(this).text() <=1) {
```

Otherwise, if you want to specifically not count numbers below 0 when you say "between 0-1", you can specify that like so

```
if($(this).text() >=0 && $(this).text() <1) {
```